# about a ninth-grade geometry problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics

My brother asked me this problem, and he is studying ninth-grade. I can't solve it using primitive tools of pure geometry. Hope someone can give me a hint to solve it. Thanks.

> Given a circle $(O, R)$ and $A$ is outside $(O)$ such that $OA > 2R$. Draw two tangents AB, AC of $(O)$. Let $I$ is midpoint of AB. Segment OI intersects with (O) at M. AM intersects with (O) at N, $N \neq M$. NI intersects with BC at Q. Prove that MQ perpendicular with OB

Here is the picture

[image]

Comment: This is not a solution, but a link to a Geogebra version of the problem.

The point $B$ on the Geogebra simulation can be clicked and dragged to reposition it on the circle.

[Geogebra version of the exercise][1]


  [1]: https://www.geogebra.org/o/TuJ5c2wB

Comment: Thanks for the simulation. @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: Can anyone tell me why I received 3 votes to close this question? I want to know so I can improve the topic later. Thanks!

Comment: There were three people having enough reputation for a close vote and not seeing the solution right away.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: yeah, I understand about that. I just wonder if I violate any rule, so they want to close this question (I can't see their reasons for closing, right?)

Comment: @leducquang Don't worry some people are reckless here. They think they have achieved something by closing question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm lucky to find this beautiful solution, and it only uses 9th-grade level knowledge to solve. Here is the solution[image]

Let P and R are intersections of BC with OI and AM, correspondingly. Let S is the reflection of M through I.

Firstly, even using 9th-grade level, we can easily prove that ${RM \over RN} = {AM \over AN}$, therefore ${RM \over MA} = {RN \over AN}$. I is the same midpoint of both BA and MS, hence BSAM is a parallelogram, therefore BS is parallel to MR.

We have this equation chain:

> $${PR \over PB} = {RM \over BS} = {RM \over MA} = {NR \over NA}$$

Therefore, we must have that PN is parallel to BA. Therefore, we have this equation chain:

> $${PQ \over QB} = {PN \over BI} = {PN \over IA} = {MN \over MA}$$

Therefore, QM is parallel to BA. The problem is solved.

Comment: @mick: let me know your idea

Comment: Thanx for the input. Will have a look at it some time later.

Comment: All the claimed results match the outcome drawings from Geogebra. Still, I don't think it is a problem for a 9th grader.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT a solution. I just want to share some of my findings.

Construction: 1) Extend BO to cut the red circle at D; 2) DA cut the red circle at E and BM extended at F; 3) OE is joined.

[image]

By midpoint theorem, we have 1) OMI // DEFA; 2) BJ = JE; BM = MF.

1. All angles marked with the same color are equal.
2. OJMI is the line of centers of the 4 circles and BJHE is the common chord (excluding the green).
3. H is the orthocenter of the isosceles triangle DBF.
4. B, G, H, and M lie on the green circle.

One way to get the Job done is by showing that MQ is parallel to either BI or GH.

Comment: I am also trying to prove $MQ$ \\ $BI$, i will upload my try later in the day. Thanks for uploading, i hope we get a good solution.

Comment: Interesting, I will take a closer look today and see if I can go on with your approach. Thanks for spending your time on this problem. It's not easy for 9th-grade, right ^^

Comment: @leducquang It definitely is not a problem for a 9th-grade unless something is missing in the given. I have tried some other approaches but also not very successful..

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing, but it is actually a problem in my young brother's notebook(without solution). I was very surprised about that, too

Comment: @leducquang Maybe your brother has the suitable-for-the-nineth-grader solution (given by his teacher, [other than the one posted]) by now.

Comment: I found an interesting pure solution, only in 9th-grade level. Can you take a look? It's quite beautiful, I think. I really like this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using only Euclid geometry knowledge, but it's not in 9th-level, so I still hope to see some pure primitive solution.

[image]

To make the problem easier, I reverse the question to be like this: Let Q be the intersection of the line through M which is parallel with AB and BC. Then we just need to prove that N, Q and I are in a line

Let K is the intersection of BC and MN. BC is the polar line of A with (O), so we must have (MNKD) = -1. Therefore, (IN,IM,IK,ID) = -1. Let P is the intersection of MQ and NI and L is the intersection of MQ and IK. Because MP is parallel with ID, we must have L is midpoint of MP.

Using the triangle KBD, because I is midpoint of BD and MQ is parallel to BD, we have L is midpoint of MQ, too. So we conclude that P and Q coincide.

Comment: One more comment, I don't see why we need $OA > 2R$.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to figure out the necessity of $OA > 2R$, too. It's there in the problem. From what I saw in geogebra, that assumption may be not needed.

Comment: Just by looking i think  if we join $N$ and $B$ and can prove that $NB$ $\parallel$ $MI$, then we are done. To do that we need to prove that $NM = MA$. Not 100

Comment: **Not 100% sure.

Comment: @ritwiksinha Geogebra showed neither "NM = MA" nor  "NB ∥∥ MI".

Comment: @Mick oh, then what about mid point theorem, i am surprised this question did not get answered after so many days and so many votes.

Comment: @ritwiksinha I have tried many methods but not very successful. The main hurdle is I cannot make good use of point N. If you like, I can upload my partial findings in a few days time and hope they could be of some help to you.

Comment: @Mick Wow i can't believe, i am facing the same problem. I actually got very close with mid point theorem but still wasn't able to use the point N. Yes i would love to know your findings, it will also kick this question back up and someone would find a 9th grade solution.

Comment: @ritwiksinha One of my tries is uploaded. See what can be done.